# PhantomJS has crashed - Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005

Tags: node.js, ember.js, phantomjs, npm-install

We have built a application using EmberJS. We got a failure message when we test the application using `ember test`. Here I mentioned the error message

OS: Windows 8(64-bit)
PhantomJS: 2.1.1

```
PhantomJS - error
    ---
        message: >
            Error:          
            Non-zero exit code: 3221225477
            Stderr:
             Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.
            PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
            <http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.


        Log: |
            { type: 'error', text: 'Error: Browser exited unexpectedly' }
            { type: 'error', text: 'Non-zero exit code: 3221225477' }
            { type: 'error',
              text: 'Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.\r\nPhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at\r\n<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.\r\n'
 }
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error too much in these days. I saw some open issues in phantomjs: [1](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14018), [2](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14512)

Comment: Do you have any async operations in your tests? Those may not be finished yet when the tests finished?

Comment: but these tests are run in linux platform.

Comment: I'm also using Windows. (windows 10, x64)

Answer (score 4):

I was having a very similar problem running PhantomJS on Windows 10 in the WSL.
I have found that:

> The crash might be originating in the QT WebSocket handling code.

Setting the Karma transports setting to polling solved my issue and PhantomJS does no longer crash on startup.

In your `Karma.conf.js` add :

```
transports: ['polling']
```

---

#### Reference Link

- [PhantomJS Crashing](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14512)