# [phantomjs.launcher]: Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Firstly, this could be a duplicated issue from [PhantomJS has crashed - Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857010/phantomjs-has-crashed-fatal-windows-exception-code-0xc0000005). I tried the solution which was given there but it is still not working for me

I set up a `webpack 4 (4.16.5)` project with `karma 4.0.0` (before I used `karma 1.x.x` but the error was still the same). It starts happening since I added more unit testing to the project (although not too much test cases).

So here's what I get when I run the test (not all the time, for example if I run it 10 times, it usually work 2-3 times)

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
12 02 2019 14:01:09.798:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.

12 02 2019 14:01:09.910:ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS crashed.
        Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.

12 02 2019 14:01:09.910:ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS stdout:

12 02 2019 14:01:09.911:ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS stderr: Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.

12 02 2019 14:01:09.915:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport error)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0): Executed 0 of 37 DISCONNECTED (5.91 secs / 0 secs)
```

I follow the link http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html but can't find any valuable information.

Here's the content of my `karma.conf.ts`

```
module.exports = function karmaConfig(config) {
    config.set({

        singleRun: true,

        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],

        files: [
            'sdk/**/*.spec.ts'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'sdk/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'sdk/**/!(*.spec).ts': ['coverage']
        },

        browsers: [
            'PhantomJS'
        ],

        reporters: [
            'progress',
            'coverage',
            'junit'
        ],

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'text-summary' },
                { type: 'html' },
                {
                    type: 'lcov',
                    dir: 'reports',
                    subdir: 'coverage'
                }
            ]
        },

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'reports/junit/TEST-karma.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
        },

        transports: ['polling'],

        webpack: require('./webpack.config'),

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    });
};
```

Really appreciate for any suggestion on how to solve this issue, it is really annoying

Comment: Is anyone can help to solve this issue?, i am also getting the same error.